# Allow user to only sudo into particular account

Tags: linux, sudo

Don't ask why I'm doing it this way but I have to.

Say I have a user name "bob" and he needs to run a program as "monitor." I want to allow "bob" to sudo into the monitor account and run the process. Obviously I could just give "bob" sudo access to run the app but I'm told it has to run as "monitor." Anyways, how can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, set your sudoers entry like this:

```
bob          ALL        = monitor        PASSWD:  COMMAND
```

*Bob* can then run the `COMMAND` under `sudo` and it will run as monitor (you can of course use `NOPASSWD:` if you want to force a password check).

Comment: To edit your sudoers file make sure you run visudo.  Don't edit the file directly.

Comment: I think that your statement has an error....  PASSWD: does a password check, and NOPASSWD: allows a sudo command to be processed without any password check.

Comment: mdpc - thanks for pointing out my deliberate typo...:)